# Why were they launching rockets in Gattaca?

Tags: gattaca

We see quite regularly in the film *Gattaca* rockets launching and we know that the protagonist wanted more than anything to fly a rocket (which he does in the end), but was there actually a purpose *for* these rocket launches ever provided?  Looking at the Wikipedia page on the film, I got the following quote:

> the Gattaca Aerospace Corporation, the most prestigious spaceflight conglomerate, with a DNA test being the entire interview process. He becomes Gattaca's top celestial navigator and is selected for a manned spaceflight to Saturn's moon Titan.

Whilst this tells me *where* they were going, it doesn't explain *why* they were going there.  Is this reason ever provided in the film, or are we to assume it is just for exploration?

Comment: I think the point is, you are supposed to assume whatever you like. In some other version, draft etc. this information may have been provided but it was intentionally omitted.

Comment: There isn't actually a rocket to Titan... It was all an elaborate ruse. They were all clones grown for the purpose of organ harvesting. 

... wait... no, that's the Island :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We're never told in the released movie, but there's a [deleted scene of a mission briefing](http://youtu.be/sC9f9Rfawcg?t=6m31s) where the director mentions how Titan "could hold the key to the origin of life".

In [a leaked early draft of the script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/gattaca_early.html), the mission is actually to an asteroid (951 Gaspra) in the "outer asteroid belt", and we are explicitly told what the goal is:

> EUGENE: (beaming) I still can't believe they're sending you to the Belt--you of all people--never meant to be born, on a mission to discover the origin of life.

And reinforced later by the director:

> DIRECTOR JOSEF: Somewhere in the dust of Gaspra is the key. Back to the beginning of the book--the life we became.  With the original building blocks who knows how far we can take "the godding".

The idea of investigating the origins of life fits well with the eugenic/genetic themes of the movie, and there are theories of [life on Titan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_on_Titan), so that certainly seems plausible to me.